# Node.js Cluster vs Multiple Node.js instance

Tags: node.js

I want to know the difference between:

```
 cluster.setupMaster({exec:'app.js'});
 for(let i=0;i<3;i++) {cluster.fork();}
```

and typing command 3 times:

```
 node app.js
```

It seems that for the internal library `net`, there are some `Round-Robin` fashioned load balancing mechanism available only in the first way, but not the second one as it is only separated node processes and there can be no synergy between them -- unless we add `inter-process communication` code.
I'd like to know that other than this, are there any other profit we can get from only the first way?

-----------------------------Update------------------------------

Listing the items where one should take care of when modeling the 'cluster' vs plain multi-process is appreciated, but it would be better to describe the hidden IPC channels which is shipped with 'cluster' library.

Comment: Adding one 'difference' I were expecting but experiments shows not exist: the require.cache is per-process global, and is not shared between each cluster processes.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that the three workers are accessed by outside apps as if they were one. So if you're running a web application, you could expose all three over the same HTTP port, as an example.  If you tried just running the node app three times, you'd have to assign a different port to each and do your load balancing somewhere else.

Comment: If you force REUSEPORT, and set them on the same port, are they not the same?